Can Neutral Current Be Zero in an Unbalanced Star-Connected 3-Phase System?
In our class, we were taught that:

In a star-connected 3-phase system, when the system is balanced, \$I_N=0\$.

Is it possible to have \$0\$ current on the neutral line while the system is unbalanced?
If yes, how can we construct such a system? If no, why? Is there a proof or something?
I have no idea where to even begin. I tried searching on the internet for a conclusion and couldn't find one.

Absolutely possible,  for example a load connected between two of the phases would not be balanced, but would cause no neutral current. some combination of leading and lagging loads connected between phases and neutral could get the same result.
The converse is also true.  Balanced harmonic loads connected between neutral and the three phases can cause a neutral current to flow. This is why power factor correction is important on switched mode power supplies. Well \$I_N\$ is still zero because it's a harmonic current so it can't be written as a complex number.

An unbalanced load would mean a non zero neutral current but, if the supply was also unbalanced to exactly counter the unbalanced nature of the load then, neutral current could be zero in a 4 wire connected star configured load.

If there exists a Neutral line then the unbalanced load would need a matched unbalanced source to rebalance 3ph. current and have no neutral current.  This is not possible to balance voltage to each phase load. You must balance the loads.
In North America with 4-wire 3-ph. and neutral grounded at source, it is unlikely to match voltage to any unbalanced dynamic load impedances. That is how one might get 0 neutral current.
When 3-phases are used both as 3-ph. loads and 1-ph.loads (Line to Neutral), dynamic startup load balancing is critical. If one distributed phase is overloaded the rest may suffer overvoltage on motor start-up at ~500% start current. The light-loaded phases of L to N will experience an overvoltage which can destroy electronic equipment well over 120% of Vnom.
Anecdote
I recall this happened on my watch as TE Mgr at Burroughs. One of our ATE functional testers blew out the ACDC power supplies on grid reclosure.  The fault was fixed by maintenance rebalancing the loads and replacing the power supplies on the ATE.  Burroughs, Winnipeg used so much electricity, the factory did not need a furnace in -40'C winter with all the power drawn by dozens of my mainframes and large 14"/8" disk drives in production on 100ksqft.
